# Simple jquery fader doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have built a really simple image fading gallery sorta thing, which works on firefox (and I'm sure worked on chrome before the holidays). However now Chrome just fades out the first image and never applies the `.first` class so subsequent animation is skipped.

**JS**

```
function doRotator(time){

$('.rotator3 .property.first').fadeOut(1500, function(){                         
        $('.rotator3 .property.first').removeClass('first').next(".property").addClass('first').fadeIn(1500);                                      
        $(this).appendTo('.rotator3');                                                                                                                             });                                      
}

setInterval(function () { doRotator(3000);}, 3000);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkyAS/1/

Comment: are you trying to select 3 different classes? rotator3, property, and first?

Comment: No, he's selecting an element with *both* the `property` and the `first` class that's a descendent of an element with the `rotator3` class.

Comment: @DavidThomas exactly. See JSFiddle for HTML (was too much to paste in here)

Comment: I've seen it. Could I suggest **a:** removing ***all*** the style tags (and use the CSS pane for relevant styling), and **b:** reduce the size of your 'gallery' (for want of a better word) to maybe three or four `.property` elements, **c:** indent and tidy up your html to make it more readable.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry about the scrappy HTML. However, the code was copied and pasted straight from Chrome Inspector, hence the inline styling etc. I'll tidy up a bit now

Comment: FYI, the code works fine with Chromium 18.0.995.0 so it's maybe a Chrome regression.

Comment: Must be, chromes stuck on 16.0.912.63 ... should I just wait for chrome to update? How long does that usually take? And chrome updates are automatic am I right?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to jQuery, did you try to post your issue in the support forum of jQuery? Maybe, they can help you to find  a workaroud for Chrome 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under each "property" div you have a div with "opacity:inherit" remove the "opacity:inherit" and it should work. let me know if there are more problems.

Here is [my solution on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcq9L/). 
I removed your interval, and made the "doRotator" run once - it was easier for me to debug

By the way - fadeIn(1500) is on your interval time. 
If your interval is for 3000 millis, and you have fadeIn(1500) - then the div will be visible for 1.5 sec.

Consider triggering "setTimeout(doRotator,3000)" with 3000 when the fadeOut finishes.

EDIT : how to force removal of "opacity:inherit" - you can simply append some JS code to force that.

```
    function doRotator(time){ 

     $('.rotator3 .property.first').fadeOut(1500, function(){                              
      $('.rotator3 .property.first').removeClass('first').next(".property")
.addClass('first').fadeIn(1500).find("div:first").css("opacity",null);                                          $(this).appendTo('.rotator3');                                                                                                                         });                                      
    }
    setInterval(function () { doRotator(3000);}, 3000);
```

Comment: Regarding the `setTimeout`, cheers for the advise. I did that initially but was just playing around. The `opacity:inherit` is caused by css3pie (rounded corners on the box)... should I use `!important`?

Comment: i took a crack at it, and realize that maybe playing around with the $.each() would also have some nice usage.

Comment: added my brute force solution to remove "opacity". I appended `.find("div:first").css("opacity",null)` after the fadeIn.

Comment: cheers @guymograbi, however that didnt work (I tried setting opacity to 1 as well) and removed the `:first` selector

Comment: yes, sorry - my bad. when I indented my response I accidentally removed a crucial space, so I had the select `'.rotator3.property.first'` instead of `'.rotator3 .property.first'`. I fixed it.. should work now.